# Stuck at an assignment - Confused as to what to do

Tags: arrays, function, processing

(Language is processing)
Hey, I have an assignment that I don't really understand. This is part 2 of another assignment, where I had to make a function called drawButton, that uses an array as argument for which button we're drawing. There's a total of 3 buttons with predetermined values (x,y,size,color) Here's part 2;

> Write another function definition called 
>   isPositionWithinButton. The function should 
>   take three arguments: a point (x, y) and a button 
>   array. Implement code in the function that tests 
>   whether the point is within the bounds of the 
>   button and make the function return true or false 
>   depending on the outcome. Call the function 
>   from an appropriate place in the code (e.g. using
>   mouseX and mouseY as the point argument) and 
>   print button1, -2 or -3 based on the passed 
>   arguments and the returned value.

So, where I am now is that I have made the function, and it can say whether or not the coordinates you typed is within the button, but I'm not sure what the last part is that I have to do.
My guess is that I have to somehow make the program draw the button if the coordinates are within the buttons coordinates? Anyways, I'm not sure how to take this on, so help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's where I am so far:

```
int[] button1;
int[] button2;
int[] button3;
boolean within;


void setup(){
  size(800,800);
  int[] button1 = {75,250,200,200,150,160,170};
  int[] button2 = {315,250,200,200,150,160,170};
  int[] button3 = {550,250,200,200,150,160,170};


  isPositionWithinButton(100,280,button1);


}


void drawButton(int[] buttonArray) {
  fill(buttonArray[4],buttonArray[5],buttonArray[6]);
  rect(buttonArray[0],buttonArray[1],buttonArray[2],buttonArray[3]);
}

void isPositionWithinButton(int x, int y, int[] buttonArray){
  if (x>buttonArray[0] && x<buttonArray[0]+buttonArray[2] && y>buttonArray[1] && y<buttonArray[1]+buttonArray[2]){
    within=true;
  }
  else{
    within=false;
  }
    if (within==true){
    println("Within.");

  }
  else{
    println("Not within.");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tweaked your code to accomplish those things. Read the comments to understand the changes.
I didn't used for loops to keep things mor close to your code as possible. Hope that helps.

```java
//read below..
int[] button1 = {75,250,200,200,150,160,170};
int[] button2 = {315,250,200,200,150,160,170};
int[] button3 = {550,250,200,200,150,160,170};


void setup(){
  size(800,800);

  // by repeating the 'int[]' part here you were
  // shadowing, redeclaring, the global vars
  // leaving those unitialized.
  // you could just delete the 'int[]' part, but then the direct
  // assining won't work. You would need to do:
  //button1[0] = 75;
  //button1[1] = 250 and so on...
  // so I just moved the decaration to global scope
  //int[] button1 = {75,250,200,200,150,160,170};
  //int[] button2 = {315,250,200,200,150,160,170};
  //int[] button3 = {550,250,200,200,150,160,170};

  //calling your draw function
  drawButton(button1);
  drawButton(button2);
  drawButton(button3);



}


// needed to call draw so skecth keeps running and you can test mouse coordinates
void draw(){

  //now that the function has a return type boolean 
  // you can use it like this

  if(isPositionWithinButton(mouseX, mouseY, button1)){
    println("hello, this is button 1");
  }

  if(isPositionWithinButton(mouseX, mouseY, button2)){
    println("hello, this is button 2");
  }

    if(isPositionWithinButton(mouseX, mouseY, button3)){
    println("hello, this is button 3");
  }
}


void drawButton(int[] buttonArray) {
  fill(buttonArray[4],buttonArray[5],buttonArray[6]);
  rect(buttonArray[0],buttonArray[1],buttonArray[2],buttonArray[3]);
}


// "make the function return true or false" 
// A function that returns something is not void
// you use the returned type instead, here boolean
// So you test and return either true or false

boolean isPositionWithinButton(int x, int y, int[] buttonArray){
  if (x>buttonArray[0] && x<buttonArray[0]+buttonArray[2] && y>buttonArray[1] && y<buttonArray[1]+buttonArray[2]){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }

  // all this body above could be repalced by this line 
  //return x>buttonArray[0] && x<buttonArray[0]+buttonArray[2] && y>buttonArray[1] && y<buttonArray[1]+buttonArray[2];

  // It says like... return true if following condition… else return false

}
```